# Rectangle polygons from single lines or point data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.5

I have point data for well locations that each have an associated bearing, which I used to create lines extending from the points:

[image]

Now I want to create rectangles the length of the lines, but of a defined width. Even better would be something that allowed me to extend a rectangle of defined width and length back from the point with the edge centered at the point, using the bearing data to determine the direction it extends back. I can't seem to find a tool to do this with either the line or point data and I don't have any experience with arcpy. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Creating basic rectangles: You have lines so you can buffer these to either the right or left as flat buffers to create your rectangles. Create an attribute and assign 'L' or 'R' to each line, create an attribute for the width and define the width of the rectangle for each, select all Ls and run the buffer tool using Field option (use width attribute), repeat for Rs. If you want the line to be the centre of the rectangle buffer normal as Flat and set the width field to half of the intended width.